# Get if some view of a Linear Layout has been clicked

Tags: android, click, focus, android-linearlayout

I want to know where any of the view of a LinearLayout has been clicked, no matter who, only if the linear layout has been clicked. I've tried with "duplicateParentState" in each view but it doesn't work.

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
              android:id="@+id/view_nuevaconfiguracion_1_layoutMoneda" 
              android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
              android:clickable="true">

    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/barra_verde"
    android:layout_width="4dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:id="@+id/view_nuevaconfiguracion_1_divisa_focus" 
    android:duplicateParentState="true"/>


    <Spinner android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp" 
    android:id="@+id/view_nuevaconfiguracion_moneda"
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal" 
    android:dropDownVerticalOffset="5dp"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: so do you want to know if any child was clicked or LinearLayout itself?

Comment: Yes! That's just I want!